# Bot ignoring commands starts with capital letters

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, lowercase, capitalize

My discord bot ignores commands starts with capital letters. For example if I type commands starts with lowercase it's working but if not it isn't working

```
@bot.command()
async def buy(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(color=0xfc0303)
  embed.add_field(name="**Help**", value="Help", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

In the above, it will ignore `Bot`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can immediately think of is to declare

```
async def Buy(ctx):
    buy(ctx)
```

While it might get verbose after a while, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`case_insensitive=True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=case%20sensitive#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive) when you create `bot`.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command()
async def buy(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(color=0xfc0303)
  embed.add_field(name="**Help**", value="Help", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('token')
```